# R - glm() formula exclude variable with conditions

Tags: r

R newbie here.

Suppose that I want to exclude categorical variable with the factor level of 4 and 5. How can I do it in `glm()` only using formula?

Examples:

```
setNames(levels(factor(df$category)), seq_along(levels(factor(df$category))))
#     1         2         3         4          5
# hardline  softline  foodline  softgoods  hardgoods

# Convert to categorical codes
df$category <- factor(as.numeric(factor(df$category)))

# Remove category with the factor level of 4 and 5
glm(resolution_time ~ division + category, data = df)
```

My objective here is to calculate the `vif`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove factor levels based on the number you can do :

```
df$category <- factor(df$category)

glm(resolution_time ~ division + category, data = df, 
    subset = !category %in% levels(category)[4:5])
```

Comment: Not necessary only based on ordered numbers. For example like factor level of 2 and 100. is it possible to do it in the formula way like `resolution_time ~ division + category - category_factor_level_2 - category_factor_level_10`

Comment: You want to remove those observations from the model data right? You should not include that in the formula. You can either do `glm(resolution_time ~ division + category, data = df, 
    subset = !category %in% levels(category)[c(2, 100)])` or `glm(resolution_time ~ division + category, data = df, 
    subset = !category %in% c('category_factor_level_2', 'category_factor_level_10'))`

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe this answer should be enough for my use case. If you have free time, can you have a quick look on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754274/r-dealing-with-new-aliased-coefficient-na-coefficient-in-categorical-varia)? Thank you.